# After including RcppArmadillo.h, errors occur when compiling code

Tags: r, rcpp

I would like to use some of the functionalities included in `RcppArmadillo`. As I read in another post on SO, if `RcppArmadillo.h` is included, `Rcpp.h` should not be included. I did just that, but when trying to compile the `.cpp` file, I got some error messages. **EDIT**. Per Dirk's suggestion, I only included `RcppArmadillo.h`, which significantly reduced the number of error messages: The minimally reproducible code is below:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

template <class RandomAccessIterator, class StrictWeakOrdering>
void sort(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last, StrictWeakOrdering comp);

struct val_order{
        int order;
        double value;
};

bool compare(const val_order & a, const val_order & b){return (a.value<b.value);}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector order(NumericVector x){
    int n=x.size();
    std::vector<int> output(n);
    std::vector<val_order> index(n);
    for(int i=0;i<x.size();i++){
        index[i].value=x(i);
        index[i].order=i;
    }
    std::sort(index.begin(), index.end(), compare); 
    for(int i=0;i<x.size();i++){
        output[i]=index[i].order;
    }
    return wrap(output);
}
```

The error message is below:

```
Error in sourceCpp("functions.cpp") : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin8/4.2.3/x86_64'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib/x86_64'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin8/4.2.3'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sourceCpp_44748.so] Error 1
```

Just to reiterate, this code has no problem compiling when I use `Rcpp.h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1. Your post is not helpful. We do not need dozens of lines of error messages, but we do need reproducible code. Which you did not included.
2. You include several C++ headers *and* several R headers. Don't.
3. Include one header only: RcppArmadillo.h and if that fails, post a reproducible example.

*Edit:* Thanks for your update.  Your code now compiles, your error is a linker error.  You simply need to install the Fortran compiler under OS X.

Comment: Hi Dirk, thank you for the reply. I updated my post with a reproducible example. Per your suggestion, I only included `RcppArmadillo.h`, which got rid of 90% of the error messages.

Comment: Thanks. That goes in the right direction, but I am at work and cannot debug your code for you.  Simplify / change your code still you know which _single statement_ causes error, then "think hard" about that line.  Feel free to ask here or on rcpp-devel if you're still stuck.